Concentration inequalities for functions of random binary strings
Let $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be a vector in $\{0,1\}^n$ drawn uniformly at random among all vectors with exactly $k$ $1'$s. I am interested in inequalities for tail probabilities for the random variables $X,Y$, where:
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}X_{i+1}$$
and
$$Y=\#\{\text{number of} \,(0,1,1) \,\text{consecutive strings in the random vector}\}.$$
For things to be properly defines assume that $X_{i+n}=X_i$.
Are there some stardard exponential bounds for tail probabilities of such random variables (say, $\mathbb{P}(X>x)$)?

Basically the main trickiness is that you are looking at a measure where it is exactly $k$ ones.  For your setting there is an easy trick: let $p = k/n$, and let $X_j$ be iid Bernoulli $p$ variables.  By a local central limit theorem, the probability you get exactly $k$ ones will be $\Omega(k^{-1/2})$. So if you get an exponential upper bound (in $k$) for the independent case then it translates to a similar one for the "exactly $k$ ones" case.

McDiarmid's inequality works fine here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDiarmid%27s_inequality
